# "Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing" Mailchimp OAUTH token

Tags: javascript, meteor, mailchimp

I have tried various implementations to connect to the Mailchimp OAuth API. Below is my current code producing the error :

```
"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"
```

I have tried x-www-form-urlencoded content type, stringifying the body and changing the headers.

```
  let body = {
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "client_id": Meteor.settings.public.mailchimp.clientId,
    "client_secret": Meteor.settings.private.mailchimp.secret,
    "redirect_uri": Meteor.settings.public.mailchimp.redirect_uri,
    "code": code,
  }

HTTP.call("POST",
        `https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token`, {
          data: body,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Content-Encoding": "",
            "User-Agent": "oauth2-draft-v10"
          },
          npmRequestOptions: {
            "gzip": true //Required to read error
          }
        }

... Code continued
```

Their documentation doesn't state anything obvious I am missing http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-oauth2/

There must be a header or something I am missing.

Comment: What makes you think this wants to get JSON send to it …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the mail chimp docs example (here https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-oauth2/):

```
curl --request POST \
--url 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token' \
--data "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&redirect_uri={encoded_url}&code={code}" \
--include
```

It wants URL form encoded post body not JSON.

Comment: For others...I had to change `data` to `params` to make it work